# Retaining lagged value to compound towards end value

Tags: r

I would like to please ask for your help concerning the following issue.

In a table-like object where each row corresponds to an observation in time, I would like to obtain the value from the previous row for one particular variable (:= p0), multiply it with an element of another column (:= returnfactor) and write the result to the current row as an element of another column (:= p1).

Illustrated via two pictures, I want to go from

[image]

to

[image]
.

I have written

```
matrix <- cbind (    
                1:10,
                1+rnorm(10, 0, 0.05),
                NA,
                NA
                )
colnames(matrix)    <-  c("timeid", "returnfactor", "p0", "p1")
matrix[1, "p0"]     <-  100
for (i in 1:10)
    {
    if (i==1)
        {
            matrix[i, "p1"]    <-  matrix[1, "p0"] * matrix[i, "returnfactor"]
        }
    else
        {
           matrix[i, "p0"]    <-  matrix[i-1, "p1"] 
           matrix[i, "p1"]    <-  matrix[i, "p0"] * matrix[i, "returnfactor"]
        }

     }
```

That is, I implemented what I would like to reach using a loop. However, this loop is too slow. Obviously, I am new to R.

Could you please give me a hint how to improve the speed using the capabilities R has to offer? I assume there is no need for a loop here, though I lack an approach how to do it else. In SAS, I used its reading of data frames by row and the `retain`-statement in a data step.

Yours sincerely,
Sinistrum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can indeed improve this. The key thing to notice is that values of both `p0` and `p1` involve mostly cumulative products. In particular, we have

```
mat[, "p1"] <- mat[1, "p0"] * cumprod(mat[, "returnfactor"])
mat[-1, "p0"] <- head(mat[, "p1"], -1)
```

where `head(mat[, "p1"], -1)` just takes all the `mat[, "p1"]` except for its last element. This gives

```
#       timeid returnfactor        p0        p1
#  [1,]      1    0.9903601 100.00000  99.03601
#  [2,]      2    1.0788946  99.03601 106.84941
#  [3,]      3    1.0298117 106.84941 110.03478
#  [4,]      4    0.9413212 110.03478 103.57806
#  [5,]      5    0.9922179 103.57806 102.77200
#  [6,]      6    0.9040545 102.77200  92.91149
#  [7,]      7    0.9902371  92.91149  92.00440
#  [8,]      8    0.8703836  92.00440  80.07913
#  [9,]      9    1.0657001  80.07913  85.34033
# [10,]     10    0.9682228  85.34033  82.62846
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed - this is enormous!